# Compare DAYNAME in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hello guys I want to compare a DAYNAME with a String for example

```
SELECT (DAYNAME(NOW()) = "monday", "ARE EQUAL", "ARE NOT EQUAL")
```

Thanks for all your answers

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. Also include **what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing** - your question does not indicate that you did anything on your own before posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT case when DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2
            then 'ARE EQUAL'
            else 'ARE NOT EQUAL'
       end as is_monday
```

`DAYOFWEEK` return 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, …